# Retrieve the cell reference of the first non-blank cell in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set (discrete monthly return series) with two dozen columns representing data series, c.100 rows representing month-end time-series. The data in the set represents the monthly performance of each data set.

Each series has run for a different length of time and is updated to a different length of time.

My conundrum is; I am looking to find, for each series, the dates of both the earliest data point and the most recent data point. I was hoping to do this by way of referencing the row headers (date) in column A. To do this I would need to know the row number of the earliest data point.

I can get the value of the earliest data point using a CSE IndexMatch, but what I really need is the reference.

EDIT

Tom, this is the data set;

[image]

As you can see, each data set starts (and finishes) at a different date.

In a summary sheet I am putting the date range for which each respective data series has data, that is why I need the row value (so that I can lookup the dates).

Comment: If you're using INDEX, it does return a reference.

Comment: Tom - Perhaps I'm being a little dull, could you help with where I am going wrong?

{=INDEX('Discrete Monthly Returns'!B3:B1048576,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK('Discrete Monthly Returns'!B3:B1048576),0))}

Comment: The MATCH would give you the position of the first cell of the column range 'Discrete Monthly Returns'!B3:B1048576 which isn't blank. What you would normally do then is to use that to select a value from another column, like 'Discrete Monthly Returns'!C3:C1048576 using INDEX. So you don't really need to know the row number in the sheet, just the position in the range. BTW I think we'd need to see a mock-up of some of your data to give more specific help.

Comment: Tom, thanks. 

I've added a snippet of what I am working with.

For example, I would be looking for TMPI Low to return row 75, then I can look up the date at A75.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your formula was fine, you just needed to MATCH in column G and INDEX into column A:-

```
=INDEX('Discrete Monthly Returns'!A3:A1048576,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK('Discrete Monthly Returns'!G3:G1048576),0))
```

I appreciate that you would want the start date to appear somewhere else, but this is just an illustration of how to use the formula

[image]

Comment: Tom,

Fantastic, works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time.

I Was wondering if I could perhaps trouble you with one small change I've noticed I'd have to make.

Because these are return values (this month/last month), the value I'm getting returned is actually one month ahead of the 'true' value. 

Is there a way I can amend it to effectively -1 month?

Comment: Yes, just take one off the value returned by the MATCH function =INDEX('Discrete Monthly Returns'!A3:A1048576,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK('Discrete Monthly Returns'!G3:G1048576),0)-1) but if any of your series started in row 3 itself, you'd have to make a special case for it.

Answer (score 1):

This example teaches you how to find the cell address of the maximum value in a column.

1. First, we use the `MAX` function to find the maximum value in column A.

[image: 1]

2. Second, we use the `MATCH` function to find the row number of the maximum value.

[image: 2]

Explanation: the `MATCH` function reduces to `=MATCH(12,A:A,0)`, 7. The `MATCH` function returns the position of the maximum value in column A. Set the third argument to `0` to return an exact match.

3. Finally, we use the `ADDRESS` function to return the cell address.

[image: 3]

Explanation: the `ADDRESS` function reduces to `=ADDRESS(7,1)`, `$A$7`. The first argument specifies the row number. The second argument specifies the column number.

---

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/locate-maximum-value.html

The answer is copy-paste work from the above link, but pasted here as reference.